# Create multipele rows based on the column value (seperated by commas) in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like the following

```
Name    Age      VisitedStaes
-----------------------------
A       20         NY, NJ, IL
B       25        
C       25         NY, IL
```

Is this possible to generate the following type of result using SQL (Microsoft SQL Server)?

I mean, if the column (VisitedStaes) has multipele values sperated by comma, it will create row based on the cell values of that column

```
Name    Age      VisitedStaes
-----------------------------
A       20         NY
A       20         NJ
A       20         IL
B       25        
C       25         NY
C       25         IL
```

**Update:**

I am trying to do that but still now I did not find any solution
Thanks

I applied with the function (@scsimon) but the problem is it is only able to do for some of the columns. Not for all of the columns like the following picture.  [image]

Comment: This has been asked and answered hundreds and hundreds of times...and the biggest take away for you need to be to stop storing data like that. It violates 1NF can causes great amounts of anguish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a splitter...

```
declare @table table (Name char(1), Age int, VisitedStates varchar(64))
insert into @table
values
('A',20,'NY, NJ, IL'),
('B',25,NULL),        
('C',25,'NY, IL')


select 
    Name,
    Age,
    ltrim(Item) as VisitedStates
from
    @table
cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(VisitedStates,',') x
```

**RETURNS**

```
+------+-----+---------------+
| Name | Age | VisitedStates |
+------+-----+---------------+
| A    |  20 | NY            |
| A    |  20 | NJ            |
| A    |  20 | IL            |
| B    |  25 | NULL          |
| C    |  25 | NY            |
| C    |  25 | IL            |
+------+-----+---------------+
```

**[Jeff Moden Splitter](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K] (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
--WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!

RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN

/* "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 1 up to 10,000...
enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)*/

  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
                 SELECT s.N1,
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
                   FROM cteStart s
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l
;
GO
```

Comment: is there any limitation for temp table data to use this function?

Comment: No @blueMoon not for splitting string data

Comment: I created a temp table #TempTable1 and then I tried to apply this. If i use #TempTable1 is throwing error. My code looks like: 
Select  
 ltrim(Item) AS VisitedStates
 , #TempTable1.ProgramTitle 
from #TempTable1 
cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(VisitedStates, ',') x

Comment: Is VisitedStates a column name in your TempTable?  What's the error?

Comment: this is the actual query to get all data from '#TempTable1': select * from #TempTable1;  the column name is '#TempTable1.CampusIds'

Comment: Then you need to pass CampusIds into the function if that's the column which contains the values to be split

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150882/discussion-between-bluemoon-and-scsimon).

Comment: I tried this way: 
select 
#TempTable1.ProgramTitle 
, ltrim(#TempTable1.CampusIds) as a 
from 
#TempTable1 
cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(#TempTable1.CampusIds,',') x


But it is giving values only for some of the rows. not all of the rows

Answer (score 1):

Scismon would be my first choice. Everyone should have a good splitter +1

However, you can't use, or want a UDF, consider the following

**Example**

```
Select A.Name
      ,A.Age
      ,VisitedStates = B.RetVal
 From YourTable A
 Outer Apply (
                Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                      ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B2.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace(A.VisitedStates,',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as B1
                Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B2(i)
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
Name    Age VisitedStates
A       20  NY
A       20  NJ
A       20  IL
B       25  NULL
C       25  NY
C       25  IL
```

Comment: Hey John, I got your point. And I tried to use your one. But the problem is the data is not producing correctly. I created a temp table and stored that but its not producing correct result.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2016 or above then you can use String_split as below:

```
Select * from #data 
cross apply string_split(visitedstates,',')
```

If <= 2016 then you can query as below:

```
Select [Name], Age, [Value] from (
    Select *, xm = CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT REPLACE(visitedstates,', ','$$$SSText$$$') AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),'$$$SSText$$$','</x><x>')+ '</x>' AS XML)  
        from #data ) d
    cross apply (
        SELECT N.value(N'text()[1]', N'nvarchar(MAX)') as value  FROM xm.nodes(N'x') as T(N)
    ) a
```